# Как записать данные в csv с python?

Tags: python, парсер, csv, beautiful-soup

Есть простейший парсер на BeautifulSoup, выглядит так:

```
url = 'https://www.avito.ru/sankt-peterburg/telefony/mobile-ASgBAgICAUSwwQ2I_Dc?cd=1&q=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find_all('h3', class_='title-root-j7cja iva-item-title-_qCwt title-listRedesign-XHq38 title-root_maxHeight-SXHes text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL text-bold-SinUO')



for quote in quotes:
    print(quote.text)
```

Как записать значение `quotes` в CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пример из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```